# ssh instruction interrupt a while cycle?

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to deploy a cluster with a script which uses a yaml file. Except for an entry called "RaftFS" each yaml entry represents a machine to deploy. I don't understand why the script does only one `while` cycle if the `ssh` command is executed (even if the command is a simple `ls` !) but if I delete it then everything is fine and it does a number of cycle equals to the number of machines defined in the yaml file!

```
cat RaftFS/servers.yaml | shyaml keys-0 |
  while read -r -d $'\0' value; do
      if [ ! $value == "RaftArgs" ]; then
       address=$(cat RaftFS/servers.yaml | shyaml get-value $value.machineIP | xargs -0 -n 1 echo)
       username=$(cat RaftFS/servers.yaml | shyaml get-value $value.username | xargs -0 -n 1 echo)
       password=$(cat RaftFS/servers.yaml | shyaml get-value $value.password | xargs -0 -n 1 echo)
       #uploading my fingerprint (in order to use pssh)
       echo $address $username $password
       echo "uploading my fingerprint on $username@$address $password"
       sshpass -p $password ssh-copy-id -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$address
       echo "creating RaftFS"
       ssh $username@$address echo "MACHINE=$value vagrant up">>vagrantscript.sh
      fi
       echo $address $username $password
  done
```

Comment: Are you sure its not just waiting to execute the remote command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no issue with the ssh command but it is a  delimiter's issue

I've played a little with `read -r -d $'\0'` and these are the results

```
echo "a\0b\0c" | while read -r  -d $'\0'  var; do echo $var; done
```

prints

```
a
b
```

and

`echo "a\0b\0c\0" | while read -r  -d $'\0'  var; do echo $var; done` 
prints

```
a
b
c
```

I assume there is some difference in the end line when the `$value == "RaftArgs"`

Answer (score 0):

The standard input to the while loop is also the standard input to every command within the while loop. `ssh` reads from standard input in order to pipe the data to the remote command. It's probably consuming the data intended for the `read` statement.

You can redirect the ssh command's input:

```
ssh $username@$address ... >>vagrantscript.sh < /dev/null
```

Or you can run ssh with the "-n" flag to prevent reading from stdin:

```
ssh -n $username@$address ... >>vagrantscript.sh
```